# Sqlite3 with php, how to create table and insert?

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I'm trying to use sqlite3 with php and i'm copying some codes from the internet, to see how it does work ... 
Well, i'm having a problem and don't know how to solve it ....

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3($_REQUEST['dbname']);

if(!$db){
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
}
else{
    echo 'Database created!';
    $sql =<<<EOF
            CREATE TABLE COMPANY
            (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
            NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
            AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
            ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
            SALARY         REAL);
            EOF;

    $ret = $db->exec($sql);
    if(!$ret){
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {
        echo "Table created successfully\n";
    }
    $db->close();
}

?>
```

If i remove , the code from my "else" , it will create the file on my directory ! But with that else , i cannot create anything !
What's the problem with that code ?

P.S. : I'm interacting that php with an HTML page which does have a < form > !

Comment: Note from the PHP manual on heredoc syntax: `The closing identifier must begin in the first column of the line.`

Comment: Move your `EOF;` to the beginning of the line. Otherwise PHP will not recognize it as a closing identifier for [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and PHP will use the rest of the script as the string.

Comment: That is so stupid -.- But it worked !!! Dankeschön !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) closing identifier `EOF;` must be at the beginning of the line, otherwise PHP won't recognize it as such and will add the rest of the file to the string.

```
echo 'Database created!';
$sql =<<<EOF
        CREATE TABLE COMPANY
        (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
        NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
        AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
        ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
        SALARY         REAL);
EOF; // <-- move to the beginning of the line
```